# How can you convert an existing resource/drawable/xml file to an Icon?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-icons

Ive a resource/drawable/xml file that I'd like to use as my app icon.  Can this be done, if so, how do you do it.

thanks,
Jim

Comment: Have you previously tried to just use it as the reference?

Answer (score -1):

yes you can ,
and if you want to convert the png file to xml you can convert png to vector xml online and convert png to vector xml with any online tool.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).